# How to get this Formik logic to work like I want the submit Button to do what I want

Tags: reactjs, submit, formik

I learn Reactjs and have this Sign in Component that uses [Formik](https://formik.org/docs/tutorial)

[image]

My problem is that Facebook, Google, and Twitter work as expected but I can't get password Sign-in to work.

When I click the `Button` the `onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {...` is called and the `values contain the email and password but I want the Button to use the same logic as Facebook, Google and Twitter` Button's`, if that's possible.

You see when clicking Facebook, Google, and Twitter they all `onClick={this.submitFormType...` that sets the state to the respective provider. Then it calls the Formik `handleSubmit`.

This is what I want for the submit `Button` also or maybe I should rethink my design not using Formik.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import { Box, Button, Container, Grid, Link, TextField, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Dots from 'react-activity/lib/Dots';
import { withFirebase } from '../../../../firebase';
import FacebookIcon from '../../../../assets/Facebook';
import GoogleIcon from '../../../../assets/Google';
import TwitterIcon from '../../../../assets/twitter-logo';
import Page from '../../utils/Page';
import MotionDiv from '../../utils/MotionDiv';
import { withEmailVerification, withAuthorization, AuthUserContext } from '../../../../session';
import { changeToUserRole } from '../../../../redux/userData/user.actions';
import * as ROLES from '../../../../constants/roles';
import 'react-activity/lib/Dots/Dots.css';
import * as SIGN_IN from '../../../../constants/signinmethods';

const useStyles = theme => ({
    root: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
        minHeight: '100vh',
        paddingBottom: theme.spacing(3),
        paddingTop: theme.spacing(3),
    },
    container: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
        paddingTop: theme.spacing(3),
    },
    facebook: {
        backgroundColor: '#3b5999',
        color: 'white',
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: '#4d70ba',
        },
    },
    google: {
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        textColor: 'black',
    },
    twitter: {
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        textColor: 'black',
    },
    button: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
        boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    },
});

const INITIAL_EMAIL_STATE = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    error: null,
};

class LoginManagementBase extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            activeSignInMethods: [],
            anonymousSignIn: null,
            error: null,
            formType: null,
            ...INITIAL_EMAIL_STATE,
        };
        this.submitFormType = this.submitFormType.bind(this);
        this.facebookSignIn = this.facebookSignIn.bind(this);
        this.googleSignIn = this.googleSignIn.bind(this);
        this.twitteSignIn = this.twitteSignIn.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchSignInMethods();
    }

    fetchSignInMethods = () => {
        const { firebase, authUser } = this.props;
        const email = authUser.email === null ? 'none@guest.ac' : authUser.email;
        firebase.auth
            .fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)
            .then(activeSignInMethods =>
                this.setState({
                    activeSignInMethods,
                    anonymousSignIn: activeSignInMethods.length === 0,
                    error: null,
                }),
            )
            .catch(error => this.setState({ error }));
    };

    onSocialLoginLink = provider => {
     // Do stuf to sign in..............
    };

    // this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })

    submitFormType = (formTypeSubmited, handleSumitType) => () => {
        this.setState({
            formType: formTypeSubmited,
        });
        handleSumitType();
    };

    googleSignIn = () => {
        this.setState({
            formType: undefined,
        });
        this.onSocialLoginLink(SIGN_IN.WITH_GOOGLE.provider);
    };

    facebookSignIn = () => {
        this.setState({
            formType: undefined,
        });
        this.onSocialLoginLink(SIGN_IN.WITH_FACEBOOK.provider);
    };

    twitteSignIn = () => {
        this.setState({
            formType: undefined,
        });
        this.onSocialLoginLink(SIGN_IN.WITH_TWITTER.provider);
    };

    emailSignIn = values => {
        const { email, password } = values;
        const { firebase } = this.props;

        firebase.auth
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(() => {
                this.setState({ ...INITIAL_EMAIL_STATE });
                // this.props.history.push(ROUTES.HOME);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({ error });
            });
    };

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const { error } = this.state;
        const { saveRolesErr, isSavingRolesStarted } = this.props;
        if (error && error.message) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
        return (
            <MotionDiv>
                <Page className={classes.root} title="Sign In">
                    <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" height="100%" justifyContent="center">
                        <Container maxWidth="sm" className={classes.container}>
                            <Formik
                                initialValues={{
                                    email: 'demo@devias.io',
                                    password: 'Password123',
                                }}
                                validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
                                    email: Yup.string().email('Must be a valid email').max(255).required('Email is required'),
                                    password: Yup.string().max(255).required('Password is required'),
                                })}
                                onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                                    setSubmitting(false);
                                    const { formType } = this.state;
                                    if (formType) {
                                        if (formType === SIGN_IN.WITH_FACEBOOK.provider) {
                                            this.facebookSignIn();
                                        } else if (formType === SIGN_IN.WITH_GOOGLE.provider) {
                                            this.googleSignIn();
                                        } else if (formType === SIGN_IN.WITH_TWITTER.provider) {
                                            this.twitteSignIn();
                                        } else if (formType) {// BUT HERE I CAN'T SET THE formType FOR PASSWORD
                                            this.emailSignIn(values);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }}
                            >
                                {({ errors, handleBlur, handleChange, handleSubmit, isSubmitting, touched, values }) => (
                                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                        <Box mb={3}>
                                            <Typography color="textPrimary" variant="h2">
                                                Sign in
                                            </Typography>
                                            <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom variant="body2">
                                                Sign in on the internal platform
                                            </Typography>
                                        </Box>
                                        <Grid container spacing={3}>
                                            <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                                                <Button
                                                    className={classes.facebook}
                                                    fullWidth
                                                    startIcon={<FacebookIcon />}
                                                    type="button"
                                                    onClick={this.submitFormType(SIGN_IN.WITH_FACEBOOK.provider, handleSubmit)}
                                                    size="large"
                                                    variant="contained"
                                                >
                                                    SIGN in with Facebook
                                                </Button>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                                                <Button
                                                    className={classes.google}
                                                    fullWidth
                                                    startIcon={<GoogleIcon />}
                                                    onClick={this.submitFormType(SIGN_IN.WITH_GOOGLE.provider, handleSubmit)}
                                                    size="large"
                                                    variant="contained"
                                                >
                                                    Sign in with Google
                                                </Button>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                                                <Button
                                                    className={classes.twitter}
                                                    fullWidth
                                                    startIcon={<TwitterIcon />}
                                                    onClick={this.submitFormType(SIGN_IN.WITH_TWITTER.provider, handleSubmit)}
                                                    size="large"
                                                    variant="contained"
                                                >
                                                    Sign in with Twitter
                                                </Button>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Box mt={3} mb={1}>
                                            <Typography align="center" color="textSecondary" variant="body1">
                                                or login with email address
                                            </Typography>
                                        </Box>
                                        <TextField
                                            error={Boolean(touched.email && errors.email)}
                                            fullWidth
                                            helperText={touched.email && errors.email}
                                            label="Email Address"
                                            margin="normal"
                                            name="email"
                                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                            type="email"
                                            value={values.email}
                                            variant="outlined"
                                        />
                                        <TextField
                                            error={Boolean(touched.password && errors.password)}
                                            fullWidth
                                            helperText={touched.password && errors.password}
                                            label="Password"
                                            margin="normal"
                                            name="password"
                                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                            type="password"
                                            value={values.password}
                                            variant="outlined"
                                        />
                                        <Box my={2}>
                                            <Button
                                                className={classes.button}
                                                disabled={isSubmitting}
                                                fullWidth
                                                size="large"
                                                type="submit"
                                                variant="contained"
                                                color="primary"
                                            >
                                                Sign in now
                                            </Button>
                                        </Box>
                                        <Typography color="textSecondary" variant="body1">
                                            Don&apos;t have an account?{' '}
                                            <Link color="textSecondary" component={RouterLink} to="../register" variant="h6">
                                                Sign up!
                                            </Link>
                                        </Typography>
                                    </form>
                                )}
                            </Formik>
                            <div>{isSavingRolesStarted ? <Dots /> : null}</div>
                            <h1 style={{ margin: '8px', color: 'red', textAlign: 'center', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                                {error && error.message}
                                {saveRolesErr && saveRolesErr.message}
                            </h1>
                        </Container>
                    </Box>
                </Page>
            </MotionDiv>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    setUserRoleToUser: () => dispatch(changeToUserRole()),
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isSavingRolesStarted: state.user.isSavingRolesStarted,
        saveRolesErr: state.user.saveRolesErrMsg,
    };
};
let LoginManagement = withStyles(useStyles)(LoginManagementBase);
const enhance = compose(withFirebase, connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps), withEmailVerification);

LoginManagement = enhance(LoginManagement);

const LoginView = () => (
    <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
        {authUser => (
            <div>
                <LoginManagement authUser={authUser} />
            </div>
        )}
    </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
);

const condition = authUser => authUser && authUser.roles.includes(ROLES.ANON);
export default withAuthorization(condition)(LoginView);
```

Comment: Why don't you just do ```else { this.emailSignIn(values) }```. I don't think you will need a form type as that would be a fallback method, right?

Comment: @szczocik Yea I tried that but it becomes spaghettis code quickly. I must control `setSubmitting` for all 4 sign-in types and also `formType` is only for Social sign-in. I went react vanilla for now so I can push an [update](https://github.com/erikswed/Greta-100-React-Web-App)

Answer (score 0):

I could not solve this now so I did React vanilla for now.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Box, Button, Container, Grid, Link, TextField, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Dots from 'react-activity/lib/Dots';
import { withFirebase } from '../../../../firebase';
import FacebookIcon from '../../../../assets/Facebook';
import GoogleIcon from '../../../../assets/Google';
import TwitterIcon from '../../../../assets/twitter-logo';
import Page from '../../utils/Page';
import MotionDiv from '../../utils/MotionDiv';
import { withEmailVerification, withAuthorization, AuthUserContext } from '../../../../session';
import { changeToUserRole } from '../../../../redux/userData/user.actions';
import * as ROLES from '../../../../constants/roles';
import 'react-activity/lib/Dots/Dots.css';
import * as SIGN_IN from '../../../../constants/signinmethods';

const useStyles = theme => ({
    root: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
        minHeight: '100vh',
        paddingBottom: theme.spacing(3),
        paddingTop: theme.spacing(3),
    },
    container: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
        paddingTop: theme.spacing(3),
    },
    textField: {
        boxShadow: theme.shadows[3],
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
    },
    facebook: {
        backgroundColor: '#3b5999',
        color: 'white',
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: '#4d70ba',
        },
    },
    google: {
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        textColor: 'black',
    },
    twitter: {
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        textColor: 'black',
    },
    signInButton: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
        boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    },
});

const INITIAL_EMAIL_STATE = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    error: null,
    message: '',
    isSubmitting: false,
};

class LoginManagementBase extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            ...INITIAL_EMAIL_STATE,
        };
        this.facebookSignIn = this.facebookSignIn.bind(this);
        this.googleSignIn = this.googleSignIn.bind(this);
        this.twitteSignIn = this.twitteSignIn.bind(this);
    }

    onSocialLoginLink = provider => {
        const { firebase, setUserRoleToUser } = this.props;
        firebase.auth.currentUser
            .linkWithPopup(firebase[provider])
            .then(res => {
                if (res.credential) {
                    if (res.user.email) {
                        firebase.doLogEvent(`linkWithPopup to Firestore for: ${res.user.email}`);
                    } else {
                        firebase.doLogEvent(`linkWithPopup to Firestore for: ${res.credential.providerId}`);
                    }
                    setUserRoleToUser();
                }
            })
            .then(this.fetchSignInMethods)
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.code === 'auth/credential-already-in-use') {
                    const anonUser = firebase.auth.currentUser;
                    firebase.auth
                        .signInWithCredential(error.credential)
                        .then(res => {
                            if (res.user.email) {
                                firebase.doLogEvent(`signInWithCredential to Firestore for: ${res.user.email}`);
                            } else {
                                firebase.doLogEvent(`signInWithCredential to Firestore for: ${res.credential.providerId}`);
                            }
                            setUserRoleToUser();
                            // remove the anonUser implications?
                            // TODO: As anonymouse the User can't change the content(viewer only) so removing should not be a problem
                            anonUser
                                .delete()
                                .then(() => {
                                    firebase.doLogEvent(`Deleted anonUser when signing in`);
                                })
                                .catch(err => {
                                    firebase.doLogEvent(`Error deleted anonUser when signing in: ${err}`);
                                    firebase.doLogEvent(`Manually remove anon account: ${anonUser.uid}`);
                                });
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            this.setState({ error, isSubmitting: false });
                        });
                } else if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                    error.message = `The email address ${error.email} is already in use by another account.`;
                    this.setState({ error, isSubmitting: false });
                } else {
                    this.setState({ error, isSubmitting: false });
                }
            });
    };

    googleSignIn = () => {
        this.setState({
            isSubmitting: true,
        });
        this.onSocialLoginLink(SIGN_IN.WITH_GOOGLE.provider);
    };

    facebookSignIn = () => {
        this.setState({
            isSubmitting: true,
        });
        this.onSocialLoginLink(SIGN_IN.WITH_FACEBOOK.provider);
    };

    twitteSignIn = () => {
        this.setState({
            isSubmitting: true,
        });
        this.onSocialLoginLink(SIGN_IN.WITH_TWITTER.provider);
    };

    emailSignIn = () => {
        const { email, password } = this.state;
        const { firebase } = this.props;

        firebase.auth
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(() => {
                this.setState({ ...INITIAL_EMAIL_STATE });
                // this.props.history.push(ROUTES.HOME);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({ error, isSubmitting: false });
            });
    };

    mailHandle = e => {
        const mailValue = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            email: mailValue,
        });
    };

    passwordHandle = e => {
        const passwordValue = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            password: passwordValue,
        });
    };

    chekvalid = () => {
        const { email, password } = this.state;
        const isEmailValid = this.ValidEmail(email);
        const isPasswordValid = this.ValidPass(password);
        if (password.length === 0 && email.length === 0) {
            this.setState({
                error: 'Enter E-Mail and Password to continue!',
            });
        }
        if (!isPasswordValid) {
            this.setState({
                message: 'Password should have more then 5 character',
            });
        }
        if (email.length === 0) {
            this.setState({
                message: 'Enter an E-Mail to continue!',
            });
        }
        if (password.length === 0) {
            this.setState({
                message: 'Enter an Password to continue!',
            });
        }
        if (!isEmailValid) {
            this.setState({
                message: 'E-Mail is not valid!',
            });
        }
        if (isEmailValid && isPasswordValid) {
            this.setState({
                message: '',
                isSubmitting: true,
            });
            this.emailSignIn();
        }
    };

    ValidEmail = email => {
        const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
    };

    ValidPass = email => {
        if (email.length > 5) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const { message, error, email, password, isSubmitting } = this.state;
        const { saveRolesErr, isSavingRolesStarted } = this.props;
        if (error && error.message) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
        return (
            <MotionDiv>
                <Page className={classes.root} title="Sign In">
                    <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" height="100%" justifyContent="center">
                        <Container maxWidth="sm" className={classes.container}>
                            <Box mb={3}>
                                <Typography color="textPrimary" variant="h2">
                                    Sign in
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom variant="body2">
                                    Sign in on the internal platform
                                </Typography>
                            </Box>
                            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                                <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                                    <Button
                                        className={classes.facebook}
                                        disabled={isSubmitting}
                                        fullWidth
                                        startIcon={<FacebookIcon />}
                                        type="submit"
                                        onClick={this.facebookSignIn}
                                        size="large"
                                        variant="contained"
                                    >
                                        SIGN in with Facebook
                                    </Button>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                                    <Button
                                        className={classes.google}
                                        disabled={isSubmitting}
                                        fullWidth
                                        type="submit"
                                        startIcon={<GoogleIcon />}
                                        onClick={this.googleSignIn}
                                        size="large"
                                        variant="contained"
                                    >
                                        Sign in with Google
                                    </Button>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                                    <Button
                                        className={classes.twitter}
                                        disabled={isSubmitting}
                                        fullWidth
                                        type="submit"
                                        startIcon={<TwitterIcon />}
                                        onClick={this.twitteSignIn}
                                        size="large"
                                        variant="contained"
                                    >
                                        Sign in with Twitter
                                    </Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <Box mt={3} mb={1}>
                                <Typography align="center" color="textSecondary" variant="body1">
                                    or login with email address
                                </Typography>
                            </Box>
                            <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                                <TextField
                                    className={classes.textField}
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    margin="normal"
                                    required
                                    fullWidth
                                    id="email"
                                    label="Email Address"
                                    name="email"
                                    autoComplete="email"
                                    value={email}
                                    onChange={this.mailHandle}
                                    color="secondary"
                                />
                            </form>
                            <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                                <TextField
                                    className={classes.textField}
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    margin="normal"
                                    required
                                    fullWidth
                                    name="password"
                                    label="Password"
                                    type="password"
                                    id="password"
                                    autoComplete="current-password"
                                    value={password}
                                    onChange={this.passwordHandle}
                                    color="secondary"
                                />
                            </form>
                            <Box my={2}>
                                <Button
                                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                                    className={classes.signInButton}
                                    fullWidth
                                    size="large"
                                    type="submit"
                                    variant="contained"
                                    color="primary"
                                    onClick={this.chekvalid}
                                >
                                    Sign in now
                                </Button>
                            </Box>
                            <Typography color="textSecondary" variant="body1">
                                Don&apos;t have an account?{' '}
                                <Link color="textSecondary" component={RouterLink} to="../register" variant="h6">
                                    Sign up!
                                </Link>
                            </Typography>

                            <div>{isSavingRolesStarted ? <Dots /> : null}</div>
                            <h1 style={{ margin: '8px', color: 'red', textAlign: 'center', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                                {message}
                                {error && error.message}
                                {saveRolesErr && saveRolesErr.message}
                            </h1>
                        </Container>
                    </Box>
                </Page>
            </MotionDiv>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    setUserRoleToUser: () => dispatch(changeToUserRole()),
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isSavingRolesStarted: state.user.isSavingRolesStarted,
        saveRolesErr: state.user.saveRolesErrMsg,
    };
};
let LoginManagement = withStyles(useStyles)(LoginManagementBase);
const enhance = compose(withFirebase, connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps), withEmailVerification);

LoginManagement = enhance(LoginManagement);

const LoginView = () => (
    <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
        {authUser => (
            <div>
                <LoginManagement authUser={authUser} />
            </div>
        )}
    </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
);

const condition = authUser => authUser && authUser.roles.includes(ROLES.ANON);
export default withAuthorization(condition)(LoginView);
```